# update a row only if all values of anothher query respect a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

let's say I have 4 tables

[image]

**The requirements are:**

If a supplier accepted an order then in the orders_suppliers table the order_supplier_status_id change to 3 .

If all suplliers associated to a specific combined order accepted their orders then in the Combined_orders table 
the Combined_order_status_id change to 3.

If at least one supplier accepted an order and all order are not accepted than in the table Combined_orders the 
Combined_order_status_id change to 2.

**My question is:** Is it possible in one query to update the Combined_order_status_id to accepted only if all suppliers accepted their orders ?

**something like:**

```
update Combined_orders 
set Combined_orders.Combined_order_status_id = 3 if(all orders_suppliers.order_supplier_status_id == 3 )
 otherwise
 set Combined_orders.Combined_order_status_id = 2
where orders_suppliers.Combined_order_id = Combined_orders.Combined_order_id
```

Each time a supplier accept an order , I would like to execute this query.

For now I didn't  find a way to do that in only one query. It is reaaly important for me to do that in one query , because from what I understand if is made in one query it would be an atomic operation.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/17/3-ways-to-write-upsert-and-merge-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` and an aggregation:

```
update Combined_orders co join
       (select os.combined_order_id, min(os.order_supplier_status_id) as min_ossi,
               max(os.order_supplier_status_id) as max_ossi
        from orders_suppliers os
        group by os.combined_order_id
       ) os
       on os.combined_order_id = co.combined_order_id
    set co.Combined_order_status_id = (case when min_ossi = max_ossi and min_ossi = 3 then 3 else 2 end);
```